# Having trouble with git merge upstream/master - how to handle a conflict (content) msg

Tags: git

I'm a little new to Git so please bear with me. I'm trying to update my local repo. These are the git steps I followed to get to my merge conflicting message.

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git branch -va
$ git branch
$ git merge upstream/master


johnsmacbook:phase-0-unit-1 johnl$ git merge upstream/master
Auto-merging week-2/5-Think-about-time/my_reflection.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in week-2/5-Think-about-time/my_reflection.md
Auto-merging week-2/4-Your-Own-Website-Solo-Challenge/my_reflection.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in week-2/4-Your-Own-Website-Solo-Challenge/my_reflection.md
Auto-merging week-2/2-Intermediate-HTML-CSS/readme.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working using either of the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

Conflicts must be manually resolved.

In general, the process looks something like this:

1. Search the file(s) identified as containing conflicts for `<<<<<<<`, `=======` and `>>>>>>>` markers. These will indicate the conflicting sections, with one set of changes between `<<<<<<<` and `=======`, and the other between the same `=======` and `>>>>>>>`.
2. Fix these conflicts. This may mean picking one or the other version, or it may mean something more. Conflicts can take any number of forms, which is why manual resolution is required. A human who understands the code must choose how to fix it.

   In either case, remove the conflict markers when you are done.
3. `git add` the files where you resolved conflicts to mark those files as resolved.
4. Once all conflicts are resolved, commit the result.

Pro Git [discusses this in more detail](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts).

Answer (score 1):

When conflicts appear, you can use `git mergetool` for resolve it.

Also, you can integrate GUI (for example, DiffMerge).
For more info: http://gitguru.com/2009/02/22/integrating-git-with-a-visual-merge-tool/